# How can I "merge" rows by same value in a column in Pandas with aggregation functions?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group rows in a dataframe, given one column. Then I would like to receive an edited dataframe for which I can decide which aggregation function makes sense. The default should be just the value of the first entry in the group.

(it would be nice if the solution also worked for a combination of two columns)

### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Test data frame grouping."""

# 3rd party modules
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'price': 123, 'name': 'anna', 'amount': 1},
                   {'id': 1, 'price':   7, 'name': 'anna', 'amount': 2},
                   {'id': 2, 'price':  42, 'name': 'bob', 'amount': 30},
                   {'id': 3, 'price':   1, 'name': 'charlie', 'amount': 10},
                   {'id': 3, 'price':   2, 'name': 'david', 'amount': 100}])
print(df)
```

gives the dataframe:

```
   amount  id     name  price
0       1   1     anna    123
1       2   1     anna      7
2      30   2      bob     42
3      10   3  charlie      1
4     100   3    david      2
```

And I would like to get:

```
amount  id     name  price
     3   1     anna    130
    30   2      bob     42
   110   3  charlie      3
```

So:

- Entries with the same value in the `id` column belong together. After that operation, there should still be an `id` column, but it should have only unique values.
- All values in `amount` and `price` which have the same `id` get summed up
- For `name`, just the first one (by the current order of the dataframe) is taken.

Is this possible with Pandas?

Comment: What's wrong with `df_new = df.groupby(df['id']).aggregate({'price': 'sum', 'name': 'first', 'amount': 'sum'})`? Does that not work for your use case?

Comment: Hahaha, ok, I didn't try it. I just thought this is how a function should look like. Nice that it accidentially actually works. I'll edit my question and make that an answer.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are looking for

```
aggregation_functions = {'price': 'sum', 'amount': 'sum', 'name': 'first'}
df_new = df.groupby(df['id']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

which gives

```
    price     name  amount
id                        
1     130     anna       3
2      42      bob      30
3       3  charlie     110
```

Comment: Is there a published list of available aggregate functions that can be applied to a column?  For example, how did you know that 'first' was a valid function?  I've been googling for such a list.  I have found a lot of articles and tutorials that mention *many* of the valid functions, but no complete listing.

Comment: I didn't know that first was in there. I just guessed it :-) To me, pandas is super intuitive

Comment: @Martin--- Thanks!

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb check out this https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/10/pandas-groupby-13-functions-to-aggregate/

Comment: @lifelogger awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: The full list of available aggregation functions is documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html

Answer (score 24):

For same columns ordering is necessary add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), because aggregate by `dict`:

```
d = {'price': 'sum', 'name': 'first', 'amount': 'sum'}
df_new = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).aggregate(d).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df_new)
   amount  id     name  price
0       3   1     anna    130
1      30   2      bob     42
2     110   3  charlie      3
```

Comment: I don't get what `as_index=False` does. Could you show me the difference? (+1 for reindex)

Comment: It is for not return index from column `id` like in your answer.