# Join strings by space using pandas aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that contains rows with some similar id's. I found a nice approach doing this with dataframe and I found the code doing this from [this] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826773/how-can-i-merge-rows-by-same-value-in-a-column-in-pandas-with-aggregation-func?rq=1) post.

Sample CSV file:

```
    id               messages
0   11  I am not driving home
1   11      Please pick me up
2   11     I don't have money
3  103   The car already park
4  103     No need for ticket
5  104       I will buy a car
6  104       I will buy a car
```

Desired output is:

Sample CSV file:

```
id   messages        
011   I am not driving home Please pick me up I don't have money     
103   The car already park No need for ticket         
104   I will buy a car
```

Now the code that I have so far is:

```py
aggregation_functions = {'message':'sum'}
df_new = df.groupby(df['id']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

Now what I am getting with this code is:

```
id   messages        
011   I am not driving homePlease pick me upI don't have money      
103   The car already parkNo need for ticket         
104   I will buy a car
```

I just want to have the space between words (eg. "homePlease" > "home Please") and avoid redundancy such as having two times of `I will buy a car`.

I already checked the post [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas) but I couldn't find my answer.

Also do i need to use `.reindex(columns=df.columns)` after the `aggregate(aggregation_functions)`

Like:

```
df_new = df.groupby(df['id']).aggregate(aggregation_functions).reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: change to `aggregation_functions = {'message':' '.join}`

Comment: @WeNYoBen Thank you. It worked. I also wondering if  `reindex` is necessary to use? thanks

Comment: Reindex has nothing to do here, that only changes the index/columns and/or its ordering. You want to aggregate the contents, not modify the structure.

Comment: @cs95 thank you for your comment. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove redundancy, I suggest `GroupBy.unique` followed by `str.join`:

```
df.groupby('id')['messages'].unique().str.join(' ')
```

Alternatively, using `GroupBy.agg` with `set` + `' '.join`:

```
df.groupby('id')['messages'].agg(lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)))
```

Both print,

```
# id
# 11     I don't have money I am not driving home Pleas...
# 103              No need for ticket The car already park
# 104                                     I will buy a car
# Name: messages, dtype: object
```

---

To return a DataFrame, call `reset_index` at the end... for example,

```
df.groupby('id')['messages'].unique().str.join(' ').reset_index()

#     id                                           messages
# 0   11  I am not driving home Please pick me up I don'...
# 1  103            The car already park No need for ticket
# 2  104                                   I will buy a car
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to have the header `id` and `message`, because I will use them in my dataframe. But based on your code and output, I am not able to have the header. Can you help. Thanks

Comment: @Bilgin It's as simple as `result = df.groupby('id')['messages'].unique().str.join(' ').reset_index()`

Comment: thanks. Sorry, i am new in python. how about if I use `df.groupby('id')['messages'].unique().str.join(' ')`? is it the same?

Comment: @Bilgin That returns a Series with ID as the index. If you call `.reset_index()` on that result, it converts the index into a column, and the overall result is a DataFrame. Take a look at the code and let me know if there are other issues.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. Now it is returning the header. One last question is that how can I get rid of that index number on the left `0,1,2,..`. I am doing sum results generated and saving them into CSV file and those numbers appearing in the CSV file with no header and it is confusing. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Bilgin Add a parameter `index=False` when you call `df.to_csv`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So it will be `drop_duplicates` first , the `agg` `join`

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('id',as_index=False).messages.agg(' '.join)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can better use `apply` with `join`:

```
>>> df
    id               messages
0   11  I am not driving home
1   11      Please pick me up
2   11     I don't have money
3  103   The car already park
4  103     No need for ticket
5  104       I will buy a car
6  104       I will buy a car

>>> df.groupby('id')['messages'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
id
11     I am not driving home Please pick me up I don'...
103              The car already park No need for ticket
104                    I will buy a car I will buy a car
Name: messages, dtype: object
```