# Pandas - Merge rows of dataframe that have a shared value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a list of items in the first row and then all the items that were bought with that item in subsequent columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['Item 1', 'Item 1', 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 2', 'Item 2'],  
                    '2': ['Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6', 'Item 7', 'Item 8', 'Item 9'],
                   '3': ['Item 10', 'Item 11', 'Item 12', 'Item 13', 'Item 14', 'Item 15']})
```

I want to merge all the items bought with each item into a single row as below:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
                   '2': ['Item 4', 'Item 7'],
                   '3': ['Item 10', 'Item 13'],
                   '4': ['Item 5', 'Item 8'],
                   '5': ['Item 11', 'Item 14'],
                   '6': ['Item 6', 'Item 9'],
                   '7': ['Item 12', 'Item 15']})
```

So, all the items bought with Item 1 form the columns next to it. As you can see in my example I want to keep all items that were bought with each item, even if they are duplicated.

I have been trying to get it to work with a pandas dataframe, however if there was a list generated for each item that would also be fine. I have been trying some kind of groupby and lambda function but I can't get them to work.

EDIT: Changed numbers to make it more clear how the final df should be organized.

Thanks!

Comment: @HenryEcker apologies, pretty new to Stack, have done that now

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826773/how-can-i-merge-rows-by-same-value-in-a-column-in-pandas-with-aggregation-func) might answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
new_df = df.groupby('1', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.ravel()[1:]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
        1       0        1       2       3        4       5       6        7
0  Item 1  Item 4  Item 10  Item 1  Item 5  Item 11  Item 1  Item 6  Item 12
1  Item 2  Item 7  Item 13  Item 2  Item 8  Item 14  Item 2  Item 9  Item 15
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) option:

```
new_df = (
    df.pivot_table(index='1',
                   columns=df.groupby('1').cumcount(),
                   aggfunc='first')
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
        .reset_index()
)
new_df.columns = np.arange(1, new_df.shape[1] + 1).astype(str)
```

`new_df`:

```
        1       2        3       4        5       6        7
0  Item 1  Item 4  Item 10  Item 5  Item 11  Item 6  Item 12
1  Item 2  Item 7  Item 13  Item 8  Item 14  Item 9  Item 15
```