# How to merge rows with same id in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following property, How Can I merge rows with same id in python?

| id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 10 |  |
| one |  | 30 |
| two |  | 3 |
| three | 10 | 5 |

what I want:

| id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 10 | 30 |
| two |  | 3 |
| three | 10 | 5 |

Comment: I think your question is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46826773/12727539).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```py
df = df.groupby('id', sort=False).max().reset_index()
```

Input:

```
      id  test1  test2
0    one   10.0    NaN
1    one    NaN   30.0
2    two    NaN    3.0
3  three   10.0    5.0
```

Output:

```
      id  test1  test2
0    one   10.0   30.0
1    two    NaN    3.0
2  three   10.0    5.0
```

Comment: This code deletes some columns. For example, my data has 12 columns, but now only 4 columns are displayed. @constantstranger

Comment: I'm not seeing that. Can you give an example of what's in one of the columns that is getting deleted?

Comment: It deletes all columns have number type.

Comment: Hmm, not seeing that either. I added a column with label `99` (type `int`) and it did not get deleted when I ran the code. Can you share a sample of the 12 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `groupby.first` to merge your same id into a row.

```
df.groupby('id', sort=False).first()
Out[18]: 
       test1  test2
id                 
one     10.0   30.0
two      NaN    3.0
three   10.0    5.0
```