# Does a flexible group by function exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

Having the following DF :

| Name_A | Name_B | A | B | Type_A | Type_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Test | 5 | 5 | Game | Game |
| nan | Test | nan | 5 | nan | Game |
| nan | Test | nan | 10 | nan | Game |

doing :

```
DF.groupby(['Name_A',"Type_A"], as_index=False)[['A','B']].sum()
NewDF = DF.where(DF['TypeA']== "Game")
```

returns the following

| Name_A | Name_B | A | B | Type_A | Type_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | nan | 5 | 5 | Game | Game |

But I would like to get :

| Name_A | Name_B | A | B | Type_A | Type_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Test | 5 | 20 | Game | Game |

Is it possible to do so  ?

Maybe I need to use `merge` instead of group by? The answer might be close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46827856/11167163) but I need to use a different group by.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I edited the post it is `nan` not sure if it is the same than `NaN`

Comment: There are various ways to obtain that desired output. Where do OP wants `Type_B` `Game` to come from? Is there any special requirement?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres it comes from sum of `B` where `Names_B = Test`. The only requirement in this example is to sum `B` Where `Names_B = Test` and `Type_B = Game` and `A` Where `Names_A = Test` and `Type_A = Game`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given OP [new requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776334/does-a-flexible-group-by-function-exist?noredirect=1#comment130285443_73776334), achieve that using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) (to be able to handle `nan` values) and `.sum`
as follows

```
df['A'] = np.where((df['Name_A'] == 'Test') & (df['Type_A'] == 'Game'), df['A'].astype(float).sum(), df['A'])

df['B'] = np.where((df['Name_B'] == 'Test') & (df['Type_B'] == 'Game'), df['B'].astype(float).sum(), df['B'])

[Out]:
  Name_A Name_B    A     B Type_A Type_B
0   Test   Test  5.0  20.0   Game   Game
1    nan   Test  nan  20.0    nan   Game
2    nan   Test  nan  20.0    nan   Game
```

Then, considering that OP only wants to retrieve the first line, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
df = df.iloc[0:1]

[Out]:
  Name_A Name_B    A     B Type_A Type_B
0   Test   Test  5.0  20.0   Game   Game
```

One can wrap all those operations in a function, let's call it `gamefunc` as follows

```
def gamefunc(df):

    df['A'] = np.where((df['Name_A'] == 'Test') & (df['Type_A'] == 'Game'), df['A'].astype(float).sum(), df['A'])

    df['B'] = np.where((df['Name_B'] == 'Test') & (df['Type_B'] == 'Game'), df['B'].astype(float).sum(), df['B'])

    df = df.iloc[0:1]

    return df
```

And then all one has to do is to apply the function to the dataframe

```
df = gamefunc(df)

[Out]:
  Name_A Name_B    A     B Type_A Type_B
0   Test   Test  5.0  20.0   Game   Game
```